# How can I implement the equivalent of a Java HandlerThread in Dart?

Tags: java, flutter, dart, java-threads, dart-isolates

I am porting an Android native app written in Java to Dart/Flutter. One of the features of this app is that it allows two users to transfer 1 or more files simultaneously between devices.

On startup, the native Java app creates an instance of a class that is implemented as an Android Service (InTouchCommunicationService) which acts as a central broker for notifications.

When user A wants to send a file to user B, user A spawns an instance of a class (InTouchShareTransfer) which extends the Java HandlerThread class. This class handles a variety of messages that get passed back and forth between user A and B.

For example, when user A wants to send a file, it spawns a new InTouchShareTransfer instance, which sends a notification to B ("Are you ready to receive a file?"), B's InTouchCommunicationService receives this notification, notes it is a request to send a transfer, and creates an instance of InTouchShareTransfer on B.

The two InTouchShareTransfer instances on A & B can now create/emit messages, which are handled by the communication service. Each message contains the ID of the InTouchShareTransfer instance it is tied to.

The communication service keeps a reference to each InTouchShareTransfer instance it spawns by its numeric ID in a HashMap.

So a flow looks like:

User A
app user indicates they want to send a file to user B
InTouchCommunicationService spawns an InTouchShareTransfer instance, saves it in
its HashMap
InTouchShareTransfer initiates the transfer by creating an initiation message: "Are
you ready to receive a file?", and sends it to the message queue managed by
InTouchCommunicationService.
InTouchCommunicationService handles pushing that message out to B.

User B
InTouchCommunicationService receives the initiation message, notes that there is no
handler yet set up to receive it, so spawns an InTouchShareTransfer instance,
and saves it by ID in its hashmap, then passes the received message along for
it to handle.
InTouchShareTransfer instance receives the message, and formulates a response: "yes,
send me your file!"

User A
InTouchCommunicationServices receives the message from B, looks up the ID of the
appropriate InTouchShareTransfer instance, and passes the response along.

This back and forth handshake continues until the file is ready to be sent, which is then done using a data channel with WebRTC.

The reason for this design, is that handling of many of these messages (including the file transfer) can take quite some time, thus they need to be handled on their own Java thread.

So here is the problem I face:

From my reading of Isolates in Dart, they are automatically destroyed once their event queue is empty. This is very unlike how HandlerThread instances work - which simply keep running (blocking) and will handle events that are submitted to the looper, until the thread is specifically killed.

So my first thought of using an Isolate to be the equivalent of a HandlerThread doesn't seem to be correct. Valid assumption?

So is the proper technique to spawn an isolate to handle every message that is processed by InTouchCommunicationService? That seems an expensive setup/teardown - since Isolates use their own memory space, etc. I haven't seen the concept of an "Isolate pool", to optimize this setup/teardown the way we have thread pools in Java.

Design suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can have a look at [Squadron](https://pub.dev/packages/squadron) which implements Isolate pools wrapping a service class.

Basically, you implement a service class and use Squadron annotations to make your service available from an Isolate (or a pool of Isolates managed by Squadron). Annotations are processed by package squadron_builder to generate code for the Isolate/Isolate pool.

Comment: I'll take a look and if it solves my issue will so indicate here!

Comment: OK, if you need help don't hesitate to call ;-)